# How to tell if a subclass overrides a method in Swift

Tags: swift

I’ve got a Swift class `Parent` that has a method `doSomething()` and I want to detect (in `Parent`) if a subclass has overridden `doSomething()`. How do I do that?

```
class Parent {
    func doSomething() {}
    func subclassOverridesDoSomething() -> Bool {
        // what goes here?
        return true
    }
}

class Child: Parent {
    override func doSomething() {}
}
```

I know I can do this with `NSObject` or even the Objective C runtime functions, but how can I do it with Swift classes?

Comment: It's perfectly valid to use the Objective-C runtime. I'm not sure if Swift offers a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Objective-C runtime provided you expose the function with `dynamic`:

```
class Parent {
    func doSomething() {}
    func subclassOverridesDoSomething(t:Parent.Type) -> Bool {
        let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(t, "doSomething")
        return originalMethod != nil
    }
}

class Child: Parent {
    dynamic override func doSomething() {}
}

Parent().subclassOverridesDoSomething(Child.self)
```

If you omit `dynamic`, it won't work because Objective-C can't see the method.

Answer (score 0):

Well Swift doesn't really offer methods to do that.

Also in my opinion, there is no disadvantage in using Objective-c methods like `method_getImplementation` or the `NSObject`. You will have to use the methods objective-c offers you to solve your problem.

For example:

```
let selector = Selector("viewWillAppear:")        
let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(YourClass, selector)
```

Comment: Does this work for non-Objective C objects? I realize both languages run on the ObjC runtime, but that seems more like an implementation detail to me, something I’m wary of relying on.

Comment: Yes, you can. I've added an example.

Comment: But it won't work for his Parent class because he has not exposed it to Objective-C.